# How can I run multiple Andy machines

Tags: android, android-emulator, andyroid

I read that I can run multiple Andy machines in the following link 
http://andysupport.s3.amazonaws.com/AndyOSFAQ44v1.pdf
but I cannot open Andy Launcher
[image]

I tried to double click HandyAndy's icon in the task bar but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe to do would be multiple emulators of different brands/sorts - as opposed to multiple instances of the same emulator?

Comment: can you suggest some of them?

Answer (score 1):

On my windows 8 machine, in the bottom right corner (system tray?) there is an Andy Icon running down by the clock. It might be hidden under an arrow. I right clicked on it and choose "Andy Launcher". You can only run one VM at a time as far as I can figure out. so far.

Comment: I have the same experience, in that it also seems I can only run one Andy VM at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer:

**Emulator as part of the Android SDK**
you can download it here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
To use just open the console /path/to/sdk/tools/android avd
and create your AVD (Android Virtual Device) and run. Or open AVD Manager from Eclipse IDE. But no emulation Bluetooth, OTG, headphones and some other hard parameters. Has a plug-in for Eclipse, easy access via adb

**Genymotion**
you can download it here: http://www.genymotion.com/
When you create a device from the network pumped his image. APK can be installed by simply dragging them to the window with the virtual machine.
Has a plug-in for Eclipse, easy access via adb and many additional tools (charge control, an accelerometer, API for tests, etc.)

**Manymo**
Here's an interesting emulator, but slow. No installation required, runs directly in the browser. To use this emulator will require registration.
https://www.manymo.com/emulators

**Bluestacks**
you can download it here: http://www.bluestacks.com/
It is best to download it from the official site. Works stable than custom build. Easy to install, does not require any additional libraries and files.
Immediately have access to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

use **Genymotion** its best way to test your app
or direct run in your phone android device turn on the **usb debugging**

Answer (score 0):

if you have the memory disk space, You can use Oracle VMware install download a live version of windows, then install andy on each one of your vm machines. I am able to run 10 andy emulators at the same time while using the setting the restrict cpu cores and threads and memory allocations.

I say live os version because in order to run live edition requires 1gb ram, or 2gb for most full desktop OS's